# What is the best practice for working with a project as nested modules?

Tags: ruby

I come from the world of Python, so I'm used to every file representing their own enclosed module, never polluting the global environment. Up until now (I've worked with Ruby for a week) I've created one file per class in a nested structure such as this:

```
lib
`- project_name
   |- sub_module
   |  `- foo_bar.rb
   `- some_class.rb
```

Where *some_class.rb* contains:

```
module ProjectName
    class SomeClass
        # ...
    end
end
```

And *foo_bar.rb* contains:

```
module ProjectName::SubModule
    class FooBar
        # ...
    end
end
```

This has incidentally worked fine up until now, but I realized that if I require *foo_bar.rb* before I require *some_class.rb* I would get a `NameError: uninitialized constant ProjectName`. So now I'm exploring workarounds for *foo_bar.rb*, all pretty ugly in my opinion:

```
module ProjectName
    module SubModule
        # Double indent for all the code in the file!?
    end
end

module ProjectName end
module ProjectName::SubModule
    # Fair enough, I suppose...
end

module ProjectName module SubModule
    # Ugly
end end
```

I suppose any of these would work and the choice would be a matter of taste, but I'd rather use the option that *most* developers in this situation uses. The question is in the title, please comment.

Comment: In ruby, it is standard practice to indent two spaces (not four). So a double indent is just four spaces, if that helps you cope with it.

Comment: @MarkThomas, this practice appeared just because some random noob from github adviced it, while others were more accurate and weren't thinking they should dictate any standart. So I will never see any sense of working under the *practice* born from some random githuber, until some huge comittee make oficially a deep research of how to indent code in Ruby.

Comment: @Nakilon the practice is widespread in the Ruby community, and is the defacto standard. For example, the entire Rails codebase uses 2-space indents.

Comment: @MarkThomas, Ruby != Rails

Comment: @Nakilon, ruby_community.include? rails_community #=> true

Comment: @MarkThomas, that totally doesn't mean, Ruby inherits Rails standarts.

Comment: @Nakilon True, but I didn't claim it did. That was an example I'm familiar with. Want others? Let's peruse GitHub for popular Non-Rails Ruby projects. OpsCode Chef: 2 spaces; PuppetLabs Puppet: 2 spaces; Sinatra: 2 spaces; Cucumber: 2 spaces; Watir: 2 spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the version with double indent and I think it is the common usage:

```
module ProjectName
    module SubModule
        # Double indent for all the code in the file!?
    end
end
```

If you don't like the double indention, just don't do it.

It is best practice to indent each code level (module, class, def, loops...), but no must.
In Python it is part of the syntax, but not in Ruby.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833641/is-there-an-acceptable-way-of-putting-multiple-module-declarations-on-the-same-l

Comment: This seems to me to be the most "correct" method. I've also started using two spaces for indenting to reduce the impact of all the nesting.